# Google recaptcha v2 encryption in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encryption, recaptcha

I am attempting to implement the secure token version of Googles Recaptcha v2, I have successfully implemented the single site version.  The issue is we will need multiple domains to validate with the same key. Following the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token#config), has left me scratching my head.  The "Encrypt your string" area is a bit vague for a new user (me).  I have tried using standard AES encryption with my own salt but with no luck, I am met with `ERROR: Invalid stoken`

Working with this post [AES encryption/decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094750/aes-encryption-decryption) has yeilded some results with encryption and decryption but I get the same error message in recaptcha.

To try and test the encryption I am following what was posted in the bottom answer [How to generate a Google ReCaptcha V2 secure token with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478724/how-to-generate-a-google-recaptcha-v2-secure-token-with-php)

Has anyone gotten this working in VB.NET?  My code currently is block for block what is in those two posts, following the second post I am getting the following outputs:

- Json: `{"session_id":"1","ts_ms":1437712654577}`
- Site Secret: `3330MgoTAAA333XFM388zn66iPtjOdQgREfZAgqZ`
- Encryption: `Ly32WGlavKyWBDBIip5IRHdZMCaeIe1077RJQ1sQ17UzNOj1SmvBQVipj3mGI32d`

You can see the format of the encryption is off, at least from what is suggested in that SO post.

Cheers

Comment: I hope that the site secret you posted isn't a real one... there's a reason it's called the 'secret'.

Comment: No it was a test account i should change it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a working example of Recaptcha V2 secure token exchange here:

[RecaptchaV2.NET](https://github.com/xantari/RecaptchaV2.NET)

It is in C#, but you can use your favorite online C# to VB .NET code converter to get it translated to VB.

Comment: This was a life saver, not only did it work but worked very well. Kudos to you and you answer.  I do have one question, did you simply rewrite the Java code they provided in C#? Their documentation on the encryption was tenuous at best.

Comment: Yes, their java code was the primary reference as there is currently no other .NET reference available on doing secure tokens. One thing to note is that the GUID session code is created each page load, as it needs to be unique per captcha request as per googles limited documentation on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I'm sure this post will be helpful to others.

Comment: I came across your example [via a question in another language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927812/creating-a-google-recaptcha-secure-token-in-coldfusion). Nice job! Agreed the google docs should be a little clearer. It would be helpful to mention things like - Hey, the reason you need to extract the first 16 bytes is to create a valid AES key ie 128 bit (The full 20 bytes/160 bit of the SHA1 hash is not a valid size) ;-). One small note, the `IV` probably is not necessary.  IIRC, `IV` is simply ignored when using ECB mode.